# How can I make the code print out every nth character of a string

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I'm trying to find how to make my code print out every `n: int` term in a given list, and here is my code

```
text = 'monosodium glutamate'
def GetNthLetters(text, n: int):
    builtstring = ""
    for index, letter in enumerate(text):
        if index % n == 0:
            builtstring = builtstring + letter
    return builtstring
print(GetNthLetters(text, 7))
```

So now my code successfully prints out every seventh term of the string, for instance, in the provided string `text = 'monosodium glutamate'` every 7th term in the string are `mit.` but I want to make my code print out every 6th, every 5th and so on until the 1st character and put the characters in order from every nth character to the 1st character.

So basically, what I wanna try to do is that make sure if the input is

```
text = 'monosodium glutamate', n = 7
```

the output should be

```
'mitouanmmo asgtoledu'
```

because it prints every 7th character of the string, and then every sixth character, and then every 5th and so on. What changes to my code do I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to just use slices with staggered starting indices and stride `n`. And then `str.join` them together:

```
def GetNthLetters(text, n: int):
    return "".join(text[i::n] for i in range(n))

GetNthLetters("monosodium glutamate", 7)
# 'mitouanmmo asgtoledu'
```

If you want to achieve this "manually":

```
def GetNthLetters(text, n: int):
    builtstring = ""
    for i in range(n):  # starting points: 0123456
        while i < len(text):  # 0,7,14 -> 1,8,15 -> 2,9,16 ...
            builtstring += text[i]   
            i += n
    return builtstring
```

Comment: I added such a bare bones approach.